# Cannot bind error while binding iLike element in app.component.ts file to like.component.ts

Tags: angular

I am getting this **error**:

EXCEPTION: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ilike' since it isn't a known native property ("
    ][ilike]="tweet.iLike">
    
                "): AppComponent@1:42

```
import {Component, Input} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
selector: 'like',
template: `
<i
   class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart" 
   [class.highlighted]="iLike"
   (click)="onClick()">
</i>
<span>{{ totalLikes }}</span>
`,
styles: [`
    .glyphicon-heart {
        color: #ccc;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .highlighted {
        color: deeppink;
    }   
`]
})
   export class LikeComponent {
    @Input() totalLikes = 0;
    @Input() iLike = false;

    onClick(){
      this.iLike = !this.iLike;
      this.totalLikes += this.iLike ? 1 : -1;
    }
 }
```

The above code is my **like.component.ts** file in which I have a heart when i c**lick** on it it gets purple and the **totalLikes value** increase by one, and when user click again it convert back to gray and value decrease by one.

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core'; // this is component decorator
import {LikeComponent} from './like.component'

@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
template: `
<like [totalLikes]="tweet.totalLikes" [ilike]="tweet.iLike">
</like>
            `,
 directives: [LikeComponent]
})

export class AppComponent {
    tweet={
      totalLikes: 10,
      iLike: false
    }
}
```

Above is my like.component.ts

[My Full Code Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m3eptw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two small issues,

(i) You have not imported **`LikeComponent`** in your app.module.ts

(ii) There is a typo error in the iLike , it should be,

```
  template: `
    <like [totalLikes]="tweet.totalLikes" [iLike]="tweet.iLike">
    </like>
            `,
```

**[WORKING STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7f6ju3?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)**